# leer un archivo en C con tipo enum

Tags: c, archivo, struct, enum, define

Hola estoy en el aprendizaje de manejo de archivos en C y del tipo enum.
Hay un ejercicio en el que debo leer datos de un archivo... el archivo tiene el siguiente formato: 40 30 20 10 10 10 20 30 #301-2# donde el primer grupo de 4 columnas representa el precio y el segundo grupo de 4 representa las cantidades vendidas de vinos.
tengo el siguiente header:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef _STORE_H
#define _STORE_H
#define EXPECTED_PRICES_FILE_FORMAT "%u %u %u %u" // <-- no estoy seguro de que esto este bien
#define PRICE 0
#define AMOUNT 1
typedef enum { price, amount } type_t;
typedef struct _store {
  unsigned int id; // store id 
  unsigned int number; // store number
  type_t type;
  unsigned int syrah;
  unsigned int malbec;
  unsigned int cabernet_sauvignon;
  unsigned int merlot;
} Store;
Store store_from_file(FILE* file, type_t type);
#endif //_STORE_H
```

En este archivo solo tengo permitido modificar la constante EXPECTED_PRICES_FILE_FORMAT, a la cual le puse;("%u %u %u %u") ya que el precio y las cantidades son de tipo natural (unsigned int).
Luego cuando tengo que implementar store.c me mareo un poco con el tipo enum, puesto a que como no puedo modificar el NUMBER_OF_STORE_VARS que vale (4) y quiero leer tanto los precios como cantidades no se como implementar la lectura del archivo usando las constantes NUMBER_OF_STORE_VARS y EXPECTED_PRICES_FILE_FORMAT
acá esta incompleto mi codigo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "store.h"
static const int NUMBER_OF_STORE_VARS = 4;
Store store_from_file(FILE* file, type_t type) {
  Store store;
  int res res = fscanf(file, EXPECTED_PRICES_FILE_FORMAT, &store.syrah,
                                                          &store.malbec, 
                                                          &store.cabernet_sauvignon,
                                                          &store.merlot);
  
  return store;
}
```

agradecería mucho que me guíen en como implementar en esta ultima función usando el tipo enum